# counts of unique values for each column based on specific value of other column python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In order to print the counts of unique values for each column in a dataframe i used:

```
for col in dataset:
        print(dataset[col].value_counts(), '\n')
```

But i want to add some condition to it, for example print these counts of unique values if other column (for example column of "num" which only has two values: 0 and 1) value is 0. 
Also i tried this but didn't give me the correct answer:

```
df = dataset.groupby('num')['age'].nunique()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You do something like this -

```
dataset[dataset['class'] == 0].groupby(['num'])['age'].nunique()
```